# Qual a diferença entre tabela, banco de dados e base de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, tabela-banco-de-dados

Os usuários de bancos de dados e tabelas que não são da área de TI, em especial pesquisadores nas ciências naturais e nas ciências humanas, frequentemente utilizam os termos **"banco de dados"**, **"base de dados"** e **"tabelas"** para se referir a objetos diferentes do que os profissionais de TI se referem quando utilizam esses mesmos termos.

Essa diferença traz dificuldades de comunicação entre os usuários de dados e os profissionais de TI, dificultando a solução dos problemas dos primeiros pelos segundos.

Pelo que pesquisei:

**Os usuários de outras áreas**: têm o costume de chamar de

- *banco de dados ou base de dados:* qualquer objeto de duas dimensões que contenha muitas linhas e colunas.
- *tabelas:* objetos com poucas linhas e colunas que contenham sumários estatísticos descritivos dos registros por grupos (médias, somas, desvios padrões, etc.), e que eles vão inserir nos seus textos/artigos.

**Os profissionais de TI** chamam de

- *tabela:* qualquer objeto de duas dimensões, com linhas e colunas, a despeito do tamanho.
- *bancos ou as as bases de dados:* seriam os conjuntos de tabelas relacionáveis por meio de variáveis-chave.

É isso? Alguém poderia dar uma boa explicação sobre essa diferença? Ela é consensual entre os profissionais de TI?

Acredito que uma boa explicação dessa distinção seria importante para melhorar a comunicação entre usuários de dados e profissionais de TI. Obrigado.

Comment: O que você colocou em "Os usuários de outras áreas" está totalmente errado. Talvez porque estes tais usuários de outras áreas não tenham a menor ideia do significado dos termos, ou confundam com planilhas, que certamente não é uma tabela de banco de dados.

Comment: Sim, é exatamente esse feedback que costumo receber do pessoal da TI da minha organização. Eu faço parte de uma equipe de pesquisa que tem profissionais das ciências sociais aplicadas (economia, sociologia, psicologia, etc.), e embora eu não seja da área de TI, frequentemente faço a ponte entre os usuários das outras áreas e a equipe de TI, e noto essa dificuldade de comunicação

Comment: Um ponto que diferencia de maneira significativa uma tabela de um banco de dados de uma planilha é que na tabela de um banco de dados cada campo ou coluna pertence a um único domínio, ou seja os valores de todas as linhas desta coluna tem que pertencer àquele domínio, enquanto que numa planilha cada célula pode conter qualquer coisa (um número, um texto, uma fórmula, uma referência, etc). Aliás mesmo em uma planilha que é tratada como banco de dados as funções utilizadas exigem a existência do domínio para cada coluna.

Comment: Existe uma teoria matemática sólida por trás dos bancos de dados, basicamente a Álgebra Relacional e o Cálculo Relacional além de muitas outras coisas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está certíssimo sobre a sua observação!

**Um pouco da história...**

Muita coisa mudou e recebeu novos nomes ao longo dos meus trinta e poucos anos de programação.

Na época, falávamos muito em base de dados nos referindo a banco de dados.
Porque o termo, em Inglês, para "Banco de Dados" é (desde aquela época) "DataBase" (algo como "base de dados").

Você não vai encontrar "DataBank" ou "Bank of Data". Ou seja, em princípio, "Banco de dados" não deveria ser o termo.

Mas foi aceito e é, de fato, a mesma coisa.
Você pode até encontrar alguma literatura que declare diferente, mas não se apegue a nada. Busque os termos internacionais, sempre que possível.

Então:

**BASE DE DADOS** e **BANCO DE DADOS** é a mesma coisa.

Seria um repositório de dados, que pode ser:

- Nosso cérebro;
- À moda antiga, uma pasta contendo papéis escritos com dados de clientes, vendas, produtos, etc.;
- Um arquivo texto de computador, com registros de dados pessoais, produtos, etc.;
- Um arquivo binário, complexo, armazenado no computador, contendo registros de dados de clientes, produtos, vendas, etc. MAS SEM, NECESSARIAMENTE, estar ativo em um "sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados - SGBD", ou DBMS, em inglês;
- Esse mesmo arquivo acima, ativo, administrado por um SGBD.
- Etc... etc... etc... etc...

**TABELA**
Desmistificado o banco de dados, vamos à tabela:
Uma tabela é, de fato, uma tabela, quando nem existiam computadores em nossos escritórios, lembra? Claro que sim!
Aquela prancheta com folha ofício riscada de caneta com a ajuda de uma régua, com os cabeçalhos:
"Produto, custo, venda, margem, estoque"

Essa representação em arquivo, em se tratando do assunto "SGBDs", é exatamente a mesma coisa.
Lembrando que um banco de dados pode OU NÃO estar normalizado, o que não quer dizer, necessariamente, que está certo ou errado. Há caso para as duas situações.

Embora existam algumas regras **recomendadas** que **podem** ser seguidas, os SGBDs não impõem que façamos as coisas do jeito "normalizado", "recomendado".
É livre! Crie uma tabela e junte tudo: dados do cliente, endereço e até as suas compras.
Não vai estar normalizado, mas isso é outro assunto e não descaracteriza ser um banco de dados. Apenas não está normalizado.

Vale lembrar que a definição de "Dados" é diferente de "Informação":

**Dados**: "18", "Rua Santa Clara", "Verdadeiro", "0", "Sim", "RJ", "Masculino"

**Informação:**: {André Assis, Rua Santa Clara, 254, Sexo: Masculino}

**Resumindo**:

**SGBD/DBMS: Sistema de Gerenciamento de Banco de Dados**:
Nome atribuído aos sistemas de computação responsáveis por disponibilizar a outros sistemas e usuários um ou mais banco de dados e seu(s) conteúdo(s).

**Banco/Base de dados**: Um repositório (recipiente) de dados em qualquer meio físico (até a sua mente guarda em meio físico). Considerar o conceito de "dados". Nesse banco de dados, podem estar armazenados registros separados por assunto.

**Exemplo**:
Banco de dados "Cérebro":
Se eu falar para você: "Futebol", imediatamente assuntos e imagens relacionadas aparecerão para você. São as tabelas específicas sobre esse assunto Futebol.
Dificilmente seu cérebro vai imaginar coisas não relacionadas.

Assim é o banco de dados tradicional: um repositório de tabelas específicas

**Tabela**: Uma representação de uma tabela tradicional, secular, contendo dados, podendo ou não estar **normalizadas**.

- Cada coluna é um campo (nome, idade, sexo, cidade, estado) ou (marca, ano, combustível, placa, cor, qtd de portas, quilometragem, valor)
- Cada linha dessa tabela é um **registro**. E o conjunto de colunas que "cortam" essa linha, refere-se a um indivíduo/unidade (pessoa ou não):
  Exemplo:

Registro 1: "{Audi Q3, 2020, gasolina, PPM1234, Branco, 4 portas, 1.000km, R$ 100.000,00}"

Registro 2: "{Del Rey, 1980, gasolina, PM-1234, Prata, 2 portas, 500.000km, R$ 15.000,00}"

Registro 3...

Observações:

- Um SGBD pode conter de 0 a n bancos de dados;
- Um banco de dados pode conter de 0 a n tabelas;
- Uma tabela precisa conter, pelo menos, 1 campo (Pelo menos nos SGBDs mais conhecidos). Assim como na vida real, senão seria apenas um papel em branco, e não uma tabela.

**Para saber mais detalhes**:
[Formas Normais (FN)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)

[SGBDs/DBMS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados)

[Tabela manual (de verdade, "Ponto britânico")](https://media.gazetadopovo.com.br/2017/10/642817c9e7e7de1b15c2353b4de9ee93-gpMedium.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Os termos costumam ser usados mais informalmente, mas existe uma forma mais correta de usar, o que nem sempre bate com o jeito que é usado.

Em geral "**banco de dados**" é usado como contração de "sistema gerenciador de banco de dados", ou pelo menos deveria ser isso, outros usos está errado. Sim, algumas pessoas usam como sinônimo de "base de dados", e todo mundo entende, em certos círculos é tratado como sinônimo. Então banco de dados é o software que gerencia os dados armazenados ali. Também se usa SGDB ou DBMS em inglês. Muitas vezes simplificando como DB ou até BD. Quando de trata de algo relacional costuma-se usar RDBMS ou mais raramente SGBDR.

Já a "**base de dados**" é o conjunto de dados que são relacionados e costumam estar unidos de alguma forma como se fosse uma coisa. Esses dados podem ser variados.

A "**tabela**" é uma porção mais específica dos dados de uma base de dados. Em geral é um termo usado em bancos de dados relacionais e indica um conjunto de linhas (também chamados de registros (informal) ou tuplas (acadêmico)) que são formadas por colunas de dados (também chamadas de campos (informal) ou atributos (acadêmico)). A "tabela" é como se fosse uma planilha. O conjunto de várias delas, em geral com algum relacionamento entre elas formam a "base de dados".

Há certos SGDBs que usam outros termos para quase a mesma coisa, como "coleções". Há produto que chama uma forma de tabela de *dabatabase*, na verdade índices também. É confuso, é de raro uso e em geral não chega até leigos (incluso aí todos que usam fortemente bancos de dados mas não se aprofundam).

Ainda tem o termo "schema" que pode ter definições diferentes dependendo de onde usa. Em geral é como organiza as informações dentro de uma base de dados, ou todas as formalidades que definem como os dados serão armazenados e validados.

A verdade é que quase ninguém sabe os termos corretos e de fato em cada área podem usar termos diferentes para a mesma coisa.

As definições constantes na pergunta, e pra mim não vi diferença significativa entre as duas versões, parecem ter sido escritas pela mesma pessoa querendo usar outras palavras, não parecem definições diferentes, são definições até com viés para bancos de dados relacionais e não de uso geral.

O fato é que as pessoas sabem bem pouco sobre bancos de dados, talvez mais até do que não sabem sobre programação, mesmo trabalhando com aquilo. As pessoas usam bancos de dados de forma muito intuitiva, elas não estudam o assunto.

O assunto é bem estudado, inclusive na área acadêmica e há definições formais e cânones. Mesmo os termos mais informais há bastante consenso entre as pessoas que pensam sobre o assunto, só falta as pessoas usarem certo. Não é fácil quando todo mundo usa errado. Eu mesmo intercambio certos termos de forma equivocada, porque todo mundo acaba entendendo assim mesmo. Pode haver algum ponto específico que há divergências.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).